# How to create both list of abbreviations and list of nomenclature using nomencl package?

Tags: acronyms, subdividing, nomenclature

I have searched for the whole day online, but all the threads indicate only realizing one of the lists by using `nomencl` package. I want to create both list of abbreviations **AND** list of nomenclature using `nomencl` package. How do I differ two `\printnomenclature` so that LaTeX could separate them clearly?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `gloss` package for the abbreviations?

Comment: Have a look at [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), a package which is capable of dealing with multiple - well - glossaries.

Comment: +1 for `glossaries`, Iused that myself, and it works great. I guess it is up to @cgnieder to make that an answer.

Comment: You can visit:
https://texblog.org/2012/05/14/list-of-symbols-or-abbreviations-nomenclature/
This is the simplest method I found..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with `nomencl`. However, there are other packages which can be used. I'll give two examples, one for my package [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) and one for [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

1. `acro`

The `acro` package allows to assign acronyms to a class and print lists for each class (also for combined classes...). This fact can be used for the task. Entries are defined with the following syntax:

```
    \DeclareAcronym{<ID>}{
      short = <short> ,
      long  = <long> ,
      class = <class>
    }
```

Here is a full example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{acro}
    
    % probably a good idea for the nomenclature entries:
    \acsetup{first-style=short}
    
    % class `abbrev': abbreviations:
    \DeclareAcronym{ny}{
      short = NY ,
      long  = New York ,
      class = abbrev
    }
    \DeclareAcronym{la}{
      short = LA ,
      long  = Los Angeles ,
      class = abbrev
    }
    \DeclareAcronym{un}{
      short = UN ,
      long  = United Nations ,
      class = abbrev
    }
    
    % class `nomencl': nomenclature
    \DeclareAcronym{angelsperarea}{
      short = \ensuremath{a} ,
      long  = The number of angels per unit area ,
      sort  = a ,
      class = nomencl
    }
    \DeclareAcronym{numofangels}{
      short = \ensuremath{N} ,
      long  = The number of angels per needle point ,
      sort  = N ,
      class = nomencl
    }
    \DeclareAcronym{areaofneedle}{
      short = \ensuremath{A} ,
      long  = The area of the needle point ,
      sort  = A ,
      class = nomencl
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \ac{ny}, \ac{la} and \ac{un} are abbreviations whereas
    \ac{angelsperarea}, \ac{numofangels} and \ac{areaofneedle} are part of the
    nomenclature
    
    \printacronyms[include=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
    
    \printacronyms[include=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

2. `glossaries`

The `glossaries` package is much more powerfull. You can define as many glossaries as you like. Here we can use the fact that a glossary for acronyms is already defined. Similar to `nomencl` it requires you to run a script to sort the entries. If your file is called `file.tex` this is usually done by calling

```
    makeglossaries file
```

from the command line. Details can be found in the [user manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/glossaries-user.pdf) (page 26, section 1.3.3).

The full example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
    
    % abbreviations:
    \newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
    \newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
    \newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
    
    % nomenclature:
    \newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
      name = $a$ ,
      description = The number of angels per unit area,
    }
    \newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
      name = $N$ ,
      description = The number of angels per needle point
    }
    \newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
      name = $A$ ,
      description = The area of the needle point
    }
    
    \makeglossaries
    \begin{document}
    
    \gls{ny}, \gls{la} and \gls{un} are abbreviations whereas
    \gls{angelsperarea}, \gls{numofangels} and \gls{areaofneedle} are part of the
    nomenclature
    
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
    
    \printglossary[title=Nomenclature]
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what are those numbers in the end of each abbreviation / nomenclature entry ?

Comment: @joxnas the page the respective acronym appeared

Comment: @clemens Is it possible to generate hyperlinks with the `acro` package like `glossaries` does? Thanks.

Comment: @cgnieder, excellent answer! Thanks! But by the way, how to *not* expand the acronym at its first reference in the text? For example, when I use "\gls{IEEE} 802.15.4", it is expanded to "Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) 802.15.4"

Answer (score 12):

It *is* indeed possible to have two separate lists using `nomencl`.

You can define them as **groups** with corresponding titles.

When doing so, you need to remove the main title by placing `\renewcommand{\nomname}{}` in the preamble.

Here is an example with two groups:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%% This removes the main title:
\renewcommand{\nomname}{}
%% this modifies item separation:
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}
%% this part defines the groups:
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\Large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Nomenclature}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{List of Abbreviations}{}}%
]\vspace{10pt}} % this is to add vertical space between the groups.
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{IMO}}{in my opinion}
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{OP}}{original poster}
\nomenclature[N]{$c$}{speed of light in vacuum}
\nomenclature[N]{$h$}{Plank constant}

\printnomenclature[2cm]

\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: may I add some suggested detail here... say you wanted this to appear in the table of contents, you could use the `[intoc]` option for the package, use List of Symbols rather than Nomenclature for the name of the second group, and then in the first `\nomname` renew, use Nomenclature there

Answer (score 10):

This also works (I couldn't get the above script working for a symbol list with units AND glossary..). Important is the order of lines here!

BasicFile.tex:

```
%Load the package
\usepackage[
nonumberlist, %do not show page numbers
acronym,      %generate acronym listing   -> Not used in this example (see line with %%% )
toc,          %show listings as entries in table of contents
section]      %use section level for toc entries
{glossaries}

%Generate a list of symbols
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{List of symbols}

%Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

%Activate glossary commands
\makeglossaries

%Load nomenclature and glossary files
\loadglsentries{nomenclature}
\loadglsentries{glossary}

%These commands sort the lists
%%%makeindex -s filename.ist -t filename.alg -o filename.acr filename.acn
%makeindex -s filename.ist -t filename.glg -o filename.gls filename.glo
%makeindex -s filename.ist -t filename.slg -o filename.syi filename.syg


\begin{document}

%Print the glossary
\printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossary]

%%%%Print list of acronyms
%%%\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long]

%Print list of symbols
\printglossary[type=symbols,style=long4col]
\clearpage

bla-bla \gls{h} \gls{nslats} \gls{illuminance}

\end{document}
```

nomenclature.tex:

```
%Some entries for the list of symbols
\newglossaryentry{nslats}{
name=$nslats$,
description={The number of slats},
sort=S, type=symbols, symbol=[$-$]}

\newglossaryentry{h}{
name=$h$,
description={Height},
sort=h, type=symbols, symbol=[$m$]}
```

glossary.tex

```
%Some glossary terms
\newglossaryentry{illuminance}{
name=Illuminance,
description={Light flux striking a surface, measured in Lux (lx).}
}



%%% In case you also want a list acronyms
%%%\newacronym{MS}{MS}{Microsoft}
%%%\newacronym{CD}{CD}{Compact Disc}
```

I don't use Perl so I type these lines directly in the command prompt after changes in any file (notice: if you didn't change anything concerning the glossary or the symbol list it is be okay to just pdflatex only once!):

```
pdflatex BasicFile.tex 
pdflatex BasicFile.tex 
makeindex -s BasicFile.ist -t BasicFile.slg -o BasicFile.syi BasicFile.syg
makeindex -s BasicFile.ist -t BasicFile.glg -o BasicFile.gls Report_Base_v6.glo 
pdflatex BasicFile.tex
BasicFile.pdf
```