# How can I display a list of acronyms and a separate list of symbols in the same document?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I want to display both list of acronyms and list of symbols in my thesis..

I tried all, from the solutions I found here... but it is always showing "acro.sty not found" and some other error with glossaries package ("datatool-base.sty not found.")

I copied as it is the code from here, even it is not working.

Can any one give complete solutions for this in detail.. Please, am not understanding.. I saw some solutions and tried but not working? Both should have chapter level (as it is like lof, lot). I read like some `.tex` file we have to create separately with list of acronyms and list of symbols and we have to call these files from our file ..is it true? Really I got tired by searching about this.

Only few days left to submit my thesis....

Comment: The `datatool-base.sty not found` error means you need to update (or install) the `datatool` package. The error `acro.sty not found` means you need to install the `acro` package.

Comment: By “I copied the code from here” I guess (from the packages you mention) you're refering to my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87223/5049?

Comment: Both errors sound like your TeX distribution is outdated and needed to be updated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which should be solvable by updating the TeX system installed.