# Nomenclature, acronym or glossary?

Tags: formatting, acronyms, nomenclature

This isn't a technical or LaTeX code question, but more of a "what should I be using for X?" question.

I am writing up my PhD. It is an Engineering PhD and I have mostly abbreviations (i.e. Particulate Matter = PM, On-board Diagnostics = OBD, that sort of thing) And there are also a few symbols (e for the charge on an electron and the usual array of greek letters found in formulae).

I haven't really been advised otherwise but these are all in one big Nomenclature list placed before my first chapter, built using:

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
```

I wondering if that is actually the correct way to do things? Should I be having a separate list for abbreviations/acronyms?

if so do I just add the acronym package? can I use just one package to do both?

Comment: If you want one package to do both you can try `glossaries`, but if you've already defined all your entries using `nomencl` you might find it quicker to use `acronym` with `nomencl`, otherwise you'll have to rewrite all the `nomencl` commands as equivalent `glossaries` commands.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks.

I have been reading the acronym package documentation and it seems rather straight forward, so I will look at using the two if the need arises.

I note, with the example provided in the acronym documentation, that it prints page numbers and uses dots to space the acronym from the page numbers. Is this formatting easy to change?

Comment: I'd use the `acro` package for symbols, abrreviations, … it allows several lists (but then I'm biased…)

Comment: related: [How to create both list of abbreviations and list of nomenclature \[...\]?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86666/)

Answer (score 5):

Having abbreviations and symbols in the same list would be confusing. Elad Den already showed one way to set it up with `nomencl`, here's an example with `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,toc,nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{gloss.tex}
%================ACRONYMS=================%
\newacronym{egr}{EGR}{Exhaust Gas Recirculation}
\newacronym{doc}{DOC}{Diesel Oxidation Catalyst}
%================SYMBOLS=================%
\newglossaryentry{sigma}{type=symbols,name=$\sigma$,sort=sigma,description={Surface tension}}
\newglossaryentry{Mw}{type=symbols,name=$M_w$,sort=Mw,description={Molar mass}}
\end{filecontents}
\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields
\loadglsentries{gloss.tex}
\begin{document}
\gls{egr} is a technique. \gls{doc} is a catalyst. \gls{sigma} can be used in calculations, \gls{Mw} as well.
\glsaddall
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.1\linewidth}
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,sort=letter]
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=letter]
\end{document}
```

I used this setup in my master thesis and think it worked great.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

you can use  `nomencl` package, I did it this way:

in the preamble add

```
%section the nomenclature
\usepackage{nomencl}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Symbols}]}{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}{}}}
```

Then in the body of the thesis (after the `\begin {document}`)
When adding a new nomenclature entry it add either A before the sorting or S depending on whether it's a symbol or an acronym

```
\nomenclature[SB]{$B$}{Some definition of B}
\nomenclature[AS]{SGP}{Some Random Acronym}
```

[image]