# Nomenclature list not getting updated

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am using `\usepackage{nomencl}` to define a list of symbols...
For example

```
\nomenclature[B]{$\varepsilon$}{Permittivity \nomunit{$Farads/cm$}}
\nomenclature[B]{$a$}{Lattice constant\nomunit{$\AA$}}
```

Now I want to add new symbols, but I do not understand why my pre-existing list is not getting updated in the output file..

Can you please help?

I already tried deleting auxillary file, but it does not help

Here is a working example: (please note the package adsphd can be downloaded here: https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~wannes.meert/adsphd/)

```
\documentclass[showinstructions,faculty=firw,department=mtk,phddegree=mtk]{adsphd}
\title{\textsc{Title of the thesis}}

\author{Author}{Name}
\supervisor{Prof. XX}{}
\president{Prof. XX}
\jury{Dr XX }
\externaljurymember{Prof. XX}{far away place}
\researchgroup{XXXXX}
\website{} % Leave empty to hide
\email{} % Leave empty to hide

\address{xx}
\date{Nov 2017}
\copyyear{2017}
\setlength{\adsphdspinewidth}{9mm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{nomencl}   % For nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\myprintnomenclature}{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \printnomenclature%
  \chaptermark{\nomname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname} %% comment to exclude from TOC
}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
    \item[\bfseries
    \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Physics Constants}{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Other Symbols}{}}%
]}

\makenomenclature%
\usepackage{glossaries} % For list of abbreviations
\newcommand{\glossname}{List of Abbreviations}
\newcommand{\myprintglossary}{%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryname}{\glossname}
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{}
  \cleardoublepage%
  \printglossary[title=\glossname]
  \chaptermark{\glossname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\glossname} %% comment to exclude from TOC
}
\makeglossaries%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Uncommented for BibLatex
\usepackage{csquotes}  %Uncommented for BibLatex
\usepackage[
    hyperref=auto,  
    mincrossrefs=999,
    backend=bibtex,
    sorting = none, % to have references appear as they are cited
    style=numeric-comp,
    firstinits=true, %added new
    clearlang=true, %added new
    refsegment=chapter,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}  %Uncommented for BibLatex
\addbibresource{allpapers.bib}  %Uncommented for BibLatex
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp} % nice greek alphabet
\usepackage{pifont}   % Dingbats
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for short intertext; somya
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelfont=md, font=small]{subcaption}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb} % for degree symbol
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{0.2em} 
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color,soul} % for text highlight
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-5pt} %to remove space below caption
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit \uF { \micro \farad }
%\usepackage{chemformula}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\citen}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \romannumeral-`\x % remove space at the beginning of \setcitestyle
    \setcitestyle{numbers}%
    \cite{#1}%
    \endgroup   
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossaryentry{md}{name={MD},description={molecular dynamics}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeindex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\maketitle

%\frontmatter % to get \pagenumbering{roman}

\glsaddall
\myprintglossary

\makenomenclature   
\myprintnomenclature

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter % to get \pagenumbering{arabic}

\cleardoublepage

\nomenclature[A]{$k$}{Boltzmann Constant  \nomunit{$8.617\times10^5 \, eV.K^{-1}$}}
An example text can be typed here !


%\makebackcoverXII

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you run `makeindex`? it would also be way easier to help, if you could provide a full MWE

Comment: Hi Naphaneal, How do I run makeindex ? (Im using texstudio).What do you mean by MWE?

Comment: MWE: minimal working example. smallest amount of code, that reproduces your problem. `makeindex` you run either via Tools -> Commands -> MakeIndex or you create a custom command in the configuration menu. Also you need to have `\makenomenclature` in the  source file and you need to have the print command at the place you want the nomenclature to appear.

Comment: hi naphaneal, Hi added the MWE in the question...I tried using makeindex but it is not working.. You can see althought the table of content shows a page number corresponding to the list of symbol.. but on that page there is no list generated... I look forward to your help..

Comment: you need to clean up your code. there are multiple instances of packages loaded or commented out. you're using `\makenomenclature` twice. also, you need to check your installation. if stuff's missing, you need to install it and have full install. after cleanup, your code works and produces the required result. btw: you can achieve your result with `glossaries` or `nomencl` alone. see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154060/nomenclature-acronym-or-glossary lastly, check your compile routine: `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `makeindex` -> 2x `pdflatex` -> `<pdfviewer of choice>` worked for me.

Comment: I am still not able to get it...when I run makeindex I get the following result: This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2017/W32TeX] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file thesis.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in thesis.ind. Transcript written in thesis.ilg.

Comment: Previously (like 5 month) ago, everything was working fine but now suddenly it does not work.. So I am wondering what went wrong... :/ (I also cleaned up my code now)

Comment: Hi #naphaneal.. thanks for your help.. in the end I found the solution :) maybe if you know you can explain to me why did it work with the changes I made (see the answer).. Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find the solution.

I am using TeXstudio.

Go to `Option--> Configure Texstudio --> Commands`
In the field of `Makeindex` write the following:

```
makeindex.exe %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
```

I have no clue what it means. But it works!

Comment: those are aux files for `nomencl` which contain the necessary information. the `.nlo` contains all the information about your nomenclature, as is. meaning they are unsorted. I think, `.nlo` simply refers to "nomenclature list object" (there was nothing about it in the documentation), which is transformed by `makeindex` into a `.nls`, containing nomenclature in a sorted manner, hence `.nls` `nomenclature list sorted` (I'm only guessing, but it seems quite right and the documentation supports this guess.) from that LaTeX gathers all needed information to create the nomenclature.

Comment: the inbetween step is `nomencl.ist`, which is the respective nomenclature style file, from which the output is generated, with regards to your source file.

Comment: With this solution, you won't be able to produce an ordinary index any more.  Instead of tweaking the default behaviour of the Makeindex binary, you should go to `Option` --> `Configure TeXstudio` --> `Build`  (i. e. one tab below `Commands` you mentioned.  There you can define user defined commands.  Press the Plus sign.  Insert `user0:Nomenclature` in the left field and `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls` in the right field and save everything.  Go to the `Tools` menu and you'll find the newly created command.

Answer (score 2):

If `makeindex` is missing in the command list (`Options > Configure Texstudio > Commands`) as on my TeXstudio 2.12.14, there is the possibility to add it as a user-defined command: under `Options > Configure Texstudio > Build` click the green cross to add a new command, name the command and type `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls` on a Linux system or `makeindex.exe %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls` on a Windows system.
Then, you can run the command from `Tools > User > <whateveryounamedit>`

[image]
[image]

Comment: This has worked for me