# Glossaries: list of abbreviations (alphabetically ordered) and list of symbols (ordered by usage)

Tags: glossaries

For my thesis, I would like to generate a list of abbreviations that is ordered alphabetically as well as list of symbols that is ordered by the first appearance of each symbol in the thesis. Having done some research, it seems to me that the 
`glossaries` package is the best package for this.

I can generate a list of abbreviations ordered alphabetically like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{ny1}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la1}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un1}{UN}{United Nations}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

\gls{ny1} \gls{la1} and \gls{un1} are abbreviations that should 
appear alphabetically in the list of abbreviations.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can also generate a list of symbols ordered by their first appearance in the document like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}
\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]

Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, merging both lists into one document is not straightforward for me as there is a clash between `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}` and `\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}` when I try to load both packages. What is the best way to merge both lists into one document (abbreviations, alphabetically ordered and symbols, ordered by first appearance)?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect the clash came from loading `glossaries-extra` (which loads `glossaries` with appropriate options) followed by trying to load `glossaries` with a different option list. You will always get an error if you try to load the same package twice with different options. (`\usepackage[bar]{foo}` `\usepackage[baz]{foo}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glossaries-extra` package internally loads `glossaries` so you don't need to load both. The "noidx" method is quick for order of use/definition but slow and inefficient for alphabetic sorting, so `glossaries-extra` provides a hybrid method where you can use `makeindex`/`xindy` for the glossaries that need alphabetical ordering and `\printnoidxglossary` for order of use/definition. With `glossaries-extra`, there's an optional argument to `\makeglossaries` that's a comma-separated list of glossary labels indicating which glossaries need processing by `makeindex`/`xindy`. These ones are displayed with `\printglossary` and the others are displayed with `\printnoidxglossary`. (Note that there's no `\makenoidxglossary`.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[abbreviations,symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries[abbreviations]

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\newabbreviation{ny1}{NY}{New York}
\newabbreviation{la1}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newabbreviation{un1}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=abbreviations]

Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

\gls{ny1} \gls{la1} and \gls{un1} are abbreviations that should
appear alphabetically in the list of abbreviations.

\end{document}
```

The build process still uses the `makeglossaries` script, which picks up from the `.aux` file which glossaries need processing, so in this case it will skip the list of symbols.

The list of symbols is in the order of use:

[image: list of symbols in order of use]

The list of abbreviations is in alphabetical order:

[image: list of abbreviations in alphabetical order]

If you prefer to use `\newacronym` instead of `\newabbreviation` you need to replace the `abbreviations` package option with `acronyms` (or `acronym`) and set the abbreviation style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[acronym,symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries[\acronymtype]

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{ny1}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la1}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un1}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

\gls{ny1} \gls{la1} and \gls{un1} are abbreviations that should
appear alphabetically in the list of abbreviations.

\end{document}
```

Here's a completely different approach where the terms are defined in `.bib` files.

`abbreviations.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@abbreviation{ny1,
  short = {NY},
  long = {New York}
}

@abbreviation{la1,
  short = {LA},
  long = {Los Angeles}
}

@abbreviation{un1,
  short = {UN},
  long = {United Nations}
}
```

If you already have an existing file containing `\newabbreviation` (or `\newacronym`) you can convert it to a `.bib` with `convertgls2bib`, which is supplied with [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls).

`symbols.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@symbol{x,
  name = {\ensuremath{x}},
  description = {position}
}

@symbol{v,
  name = {\ensuremath{v}},
  description = {velocity}
}

@symbol{a,
  name = {\ensuremath{a}},
  description = {acceleration}
}

@symbol{t,
  name = {\ensuremath{t}},
  description = {time}
}

@symbol{F,
  name = {\ensuremath{F}},
  description = {force}
}
```

Again, if you already have an existing file containing `\glsxtrnewsymbol` you can convert it to a `.bib` file with `convertgls2bib`.

Document (`test.tex`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
 abbreviations,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={abbreviations},% data in abbreviations.bib
  sort={en}, % sort by this language tag (en = English)
  type=abbreviations, % put the entries in this glossary
  save-locations=false % no number list required
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={symbols}, % data in symbols.bib
  sort={use}, % sort by order of use
  type=symbols, % put the entries in this glossary
  save-locations=false % no number list required
]


\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]

Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

\gls{ny1} \gls{la1} and \gls{un1} are abbreviations that should
appear alphabetically in the list of abbreviations.

\end{document}
```

The document build is:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls test
pdflatex test
```

By default `bib2gls` doesn't form letter groups, so there's no need for the `nogroupskip` option now. If you decide that you do actually want letter groups you need to add the `--group` or `-g` switch:

```
bib2gls -g test
```

The list of symbols is as before:

[image: list of symbols in order of use]

and the list of abbreviations is again in alphabetical order:

[image: list of abbreviations in alphabetical order]

This provides a more flexible way of applying different ordering to different glossaries.

If your TeX distribution is too old to support either the hybrid method or the `bib2gls` method, you can use the `\makenoidxglossaries` method with just the base `glossaries` package as in the other answer, but with `glossaries-extra` you can still use `\glsxtrnewsymbol` if you have the `symbols` package option as that command has been available since the first release of `glossaries-extra`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[abbreviations,symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\newabbreviation{ny1}{NY}{New York}
\newabbreviation{la1}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newabbreviation{un1}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printnoidxglossary[type=abbreviations]

Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

\gls{ny1} \gls{la1} and \gls{un1} are abbreviations that should
appear alphabetically in the list of abbreviations.

\end{document}
```

The advantage is that the code is a bit more compact.

Comment: Thank you, but, using Overleaf, I can't compile the first two examples you gave. It doesn't like `\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]`.The error message is `LaTeX Error: \@glo@assign@sortkey undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ... l.55 ...rt=use,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]`

Comment: @BJPrim It seems that Overleaf has an old version of `glossaries-extra` (2016/08/15 v1.07). The latest version is currently 1.36 2018-08-18. The Overleaf version is also too old for the `bib2gls` example (and I'm guessing bib2gls isn't installed on Overleaf).

Comment: Oh OK, that's a shame. I will go with NBur's option then but still accept your answer as the best one due to the comprehensive documentation.

Comment: @BJPrim Yes, it's a shame. They could really do with updating their TeX distribution. (And thanks `:-)` )

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276174/151808) by @Grimler: I removed the `filecontents` and changed the sort type for symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,toc,nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
%\begin{filecontents}{gloss.tex}
    %================ACRONYMS=================%
    \newacronym{ny1}{NY}{New York}
    \newacronym{la1}{LA}{Los Angeles}
    \newacronym{un1}{UN}{United Nations}
    %================SYMBOLS=================%
    \newglossaryentry{x}{type=symbols,name=\ensuremath{x},sort=x,description={position}}
    \newglossaryentry{v}{type=symbols,name=\ensuremath{v},sort=v,description={velocity}}
    \newglossaryentry{a}{type=symbols,name=\ensuremath{a},sort=a,description={acceleration}}
    \newglossaryentry{t}{type=symbols,name=\ensuremath{t},sort=t,description={time}}
    \newglossaryentry{F}{type=symbols,name=\ensuremath{F},sort=F,description={force}}
%\end{filecontents}
\makenoidxglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields
%\loadglsentries{gloss.tex}
\begin{document}
    \gls{ny1} \gls{la1} and \gls{un1} are abbreviations that should 
    appear alphabetically in the list of abbreviations.

    Reference symbols: $\gls{F}$, $\gls{t}$, $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$.

    \glsaddall
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.5\linewidth}
    \setlength{\glspagelistwidth}{0.1\linewidth}
    \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,sort=letter,title=Abbreviations]
    \printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=use]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work! I am just wondering what a command like "sort=x" does?

Comment: In case you use `\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,sort=letter]`, you can force your `\newglossaryentry` to be sorted in the right way. For instance, sort $$\vec{A}$$ as A.