# List of acronyms in Fancy Table

Tags: acronyms, acro

I wanted to know what will be the best way to get my list of abbreviations to show up like:

[image]

Here is some code modified from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl) in order to generate the list of abbreviations:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{acro}

% probably a good idea for the nomenclature entries:
\acsetup{first-style=short}

 %class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{PLL}{
  short = PLL ,
  long  = Phase Locked Loop ,
  class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{HP}{
  short = HP ,
  long  = High Port ,
  class = abbrev
}

\DeclareAcronym{LP}{
  short = LP ,
  long  = Low Port ,
  class = abbrev
}


\begin{document}

\ac{HP}, \ac{PLL} and \ac{LP} are abbreviations whereas
are part of the nomenclature

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=List of Abbreviations]


\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get an acronym list similar to the one in the picture you need at least v2.6e (2016/09/04) of `acro`.

You need to declare a new instance of the `acro-list` object and provide the template code for the new instance. Unfortunately this still requires use of some internal variables but their usage should be safe enough.

With the help of `colortbl` and `tabu` the rest is just adding the “fancy” stuff:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{acro,tabu,longtable,xcolor,colortbl}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__acro_fancy_color_tl

% a new interface for the acro-list:
\DeclareTemplateInterface {acro-list} {fancy-table} {2}
  {
    foreign-sep : tokenlist = {~} ,
    before      : tokenlist = ,
    after       : tokenlist = ,
    color       : tokenlist = red!20
  }

% now the code for the new interface -- similar to existing ones but adding
% the `fancy' stuff:
\DeclareTemplateCode {acro-list} {fancy-table} {2}
  {
    foreign-sep = \l__acro_foreign_sep_tl ,
    before      = \l__acro_list_before_tl ,
    after       = \l__acro_list_after_tl ,
    color       = \l__acro_fancy_color_tl
  }
  {
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \acro_activate_hyperref_support:
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_print_list_entry:nnnn ##1##2##3##4
      {
        ##1 \strut &
        \cellcolor {\l__acro_fancy_color_tl} \strut ##3 ##2 ##4 \strut \\
        \strut & \\
      }
    \acro_build_list_entries:Nnn \l__acro_list_entries_tl {#1} {#2}
    \tabulinesep = 1.2pt
    \extrarowsep = 1.2pt
    \tabulinestyle { 1.2pt \l__acro_fancy_color_tl }
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_before_tl
        \exp_not:n
          {
            \begin {longtabu} to \linewidth {X[1,r]|X[4]|}
              \multicolumn {1} {r} {\bfseries\itshape Abbreviation} &
              \multicolumn {1} {l} {\bfseries Explanation} \\
              \tabucline-
          }
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_entries_tl
        \exp_not:N \end {longtabu}
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_after_tl
      }
  }

% at last we need to provide at least one style using the instance:
\DeclareAcroListStyle {joe} {fancy-table} { color = blue!20 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\acsetup{
  first-style = short ,
  list-style = joe , % we use the newly defined style
  list-short-format = \itshape
}

\DeclareAcronym{PLL}{
  short = PLL ,
  long  = Phase Locked Loop
}

\DeclareAcronym{HP}{
  short = HP ,
  long  = High Port
}

\DeclareAcronym{LP}{
  short = LP ,
  long  = Low Port
}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}% I assumed this from the picture

\begin{document}

\ac{HP}, \ac{PLL} and \ac{LP} are abbreviations

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: THANKS for your response.  For some reason, I get the error, `\template code > acro-list/fancy-table ...ies:Nnn     \l__acro_list_entries_t1 {...`  Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have an up to date tex distribution?