# How to patch result of \DeclareTemplateCode (for custom acro list style)

Tags: longtable, latex3, patching, acro, xtemplate

In trying to create a custom [`acro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/acro) list style with a `longtable` and repeating heading, I started working my way through some LaTeX3 code more than I have in the past.  I am used to patching with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`, but was stumped when trying to change a Template created via some code in `acro.sty`.

#### Goal

I want to change/add variables to the `\DeclareAcroListStyle` procedure to allow lines of the tables to be added before and after the acronym content, but *inside* the `longtable` environment.  This would allow, for example, a header row with `\endhead` to be inserted to support a multiple-page table.

#### Minimum Working Example

This MWE gives a table and an example of how I would want the code to operate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro,longtable}

\DeclareAcronym{test}{short = ST, long  = Some Test}

% Define a new format type
\DeclareAcroListStyle{newstyle}{table}{
table = longtable,
table-spec = ll,
before = This text is before the \texttt{\textbackslash begin\{...\}} element.,
after = \noindent This text is after the \texttt{\textbackslash end\{...\}} element.,
%%% Want to add these variables to put header into table:
% beforeinner = \hrule Acronym & Definition \\\endhead,
% afterinner = \hrule
}
\acsetup{list-style=newstyle}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is \ac{test}.
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

#### Changes in the source code

I have solved my overall problem by copying and modifying the `acro.sty` in its entirety.  Now, I am trying to get this done via a patch, so I don't have to copy the entire style file.  The portion that I had to edit was lines 1795-1837 (6 lines added in code below, current version of `acro` package being v2.6e 2016/09/04).

```
% `table' template:
\DeclareTemplateInterface {acro-list} {table} {2}
  {
    table       : tokenlist = tabular ,
    table-spec  : tokenlist = lp{.7\linewidth} ,
    foreign-sep : tokenlist = {~} ,
    reverse     : boolean   = false ,
    before      : tokenlist = ,
    after       : tokenlist = ,
    beforeinner : tokenlist = ,  %%% ADDED
    afterinner  : tokenlist =    %%% ADDED
  }

\DeclareTemplateCode {acro-list} {table} {2}
  {
    table       = \l__acro_list_table_tl      ,
    table-spec  = \l__acro_list_table_spec_tl ,
    foreign-sep = \l__acro_foreign_sep_tl ,
    reverse     = \l__acro_list_reverse_long_extra_bool ,
    before      = \l__acro_list_before_tl ,
    after       = \l__acro_list_after_tl ,
    beforeinner = \l__acro_list_beforeinner_tl ,   %%% ADDED
    afterinner  = \l__acro_list_afterinner_tl      %%% ADDED
  }
  {
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \acro_activate_hyperref_support:
    \bool_if:NTF \l__acro_list_reverse_long_extra_bool
      {
        \cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_print_list_entry:nnnn ##1##2##3##4
          { ##1 & ##3 ##2 ##4 \tabularnewline }
      }
      {
        \cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_print_list_entry:nnnn ##1##2##3##4
          { ##1 & ##2 ##3 ##4 \tabularnewline }
      }
    \acro_build_list_entries:Nnn \l__acro_list_entries_tl {#1} {#2}
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_before_tl
        \exp_not:N \begin { \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_table_tl }
          { \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_table_spec_tl }
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_beforeinner_tl %%% ADDED
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_entries_tl
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_afterinner_tl  %%% ADDED
        \exp_not:N \end { \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_table_tl }
        \exp_not:V \l__acro_list_after_tl
      }
  }
```

It seems like I could modify the template *interface* after creation with [`xtemplate`'s](http://ctan.org/pkg/xtemplate) `\EditInstance`, but I haven't actually confirmed that yet.

I can't figure out if/how I would be able to modify the template *code* in any similar fashion.

---

I would entertain any easier methods of solving the original problem  (adding running header to `longtable` style with `acro`) in comments, but the real question is patching the template code in LaTeX3.

Comment: I did very much the same here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295827/5049

Comment: This other question gives good info as well; I tried this first, but was stuck without really knowing about `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\tl_new:N` yet...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already covered in [List of acronyms in Fancy Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295827/list-of-acronyms-in-fancy-table), creating a new template which happens to be similar to an existing one is entirely acceptable. Indeed, given the way the `xtemplate` code is set up, patching to alter *interfaces* is pretty tricky: to support the way *concept* is meant to work there are various internal structures one would have to alter.

At a conceptual level, the idea of a template here is to have a fixed 'designer' interface implementing some feature. There can be more than one template that do different things: one question of course is how far each template goes before one needs a different one. For a case where you need new parameters, either you need a new template or you need to get the original template author to extend it.

Whilst it's not officially supported, if you only want to alter the code part of a template that is doable as you can find the code in it's 'internal' location

```
\expandafter\patchcmd
  \csname\c__xtemplate_code_root_tl acro-list/table\endcname
  ...
```

---

It's worth noting here that `xtemplate` is experimental and has been used by the team to explore ways of providing a designer interface to parts of a document, but that it's not necessarily the 'final word'. Indeed, the team have concluded that some of the (deliberate) limitations of `xtemplate` mean that it's not the best long-term solution to the problem. The code does a poor job of dealing with context-dependent definitions, and as we can see here there's no (simple) inheritance available. As such, new ideas are being worked on and hopefully will emerge sooner rather than later!

Comment: The internal macro was what I was having trouble identifying; I figured at some point it came down to that.  Looking forward to seeing how LaTeX3 evolves.