# Nomenclature - Glossary

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

I am trying to add a glossary to my `.tex` file.
A part of my code is:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
%Glossary
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}
\include{Glossary}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

In file `Glossary.tex` I have things like:

`\nomenclature{thing1}{definition of thing1}`

My problem is: when I get the `.pdf` file "Nomenclature" appears in the top of the page. I want it to be renamed "Glossary". What should I do?

Comment: `\def\nomname{Glossary}` most likely. Please don't post such fragments only and loading `imakeidx` and `makeidx` together is not recommended!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, what if I want to put a Nomenclature (with symbols definitions) and a Glossary (with terms definitions)?

Comment: Use the `glossaries` package -- that's easier!

Comment: This question may help regarding the use of multiple such lists http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the original question (but not the follow up question in the comments)

The name of the nomenclature is defined in `\nomname`. Redefinition to `Glossary` is quite straightforward!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossary}
\makenomenclature

\nomenclature{$x$}{a variable}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\blindtext
\clearpage
\printnomenclature
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}
\end{document}
```