# List of Abbreviations not showing up using \makeglossaries

Tags: acronyms

I would like to get the List of Abbreviations to show up in my document.

I am using the `glossary` code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl) and cannot get the list of abbreviations to show up.  I took the following steps:

1. I installed pearl script.
2. I then downloaded and placed the `makeglossaries.bat` and `makeglossaries.txt` into a folder name `makeglossaries` and placed that folder in the path `C:\Users\mycomputer\makeglossaries`
3. I then modified the `makeglossaries.bat` file by changing the original command to `perl -S %makeglossaries_path%\makeglossaries "%~n1"`.

I am using WinEdt and when I run `PDFLaTeXify`, I get the warning

`Can't open pearl script "\makeglossaries": No such file or directory`

I see that the `.acn` file is created with the glossentries.

Can you tell me how to get the List of Abbreviations to show up in the document?

I did look at the other posts concerning this issue but could still not figure out a solution.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% abbreviations:
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}

% nomenclature:
\newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
  name = $a$ ,
  description = The number of angels per unit area,
}
\newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
  name = $N$ ,
  description = The number of angels per needle point
}
\newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
  name = $A$ ,
  description = The area of the needle point
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\gls{ny}, \gls{la} and \gls{un} are abbreviations whereas
\gls{angelsperarea}, \gls{numofangels} and \gls{areaofneedle} are part of the
nomenclature

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

\printglossary[title=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that the environment variable `%makeglossaries_path%` isn't set on your system. You'll need to set it to the appropriate path.

Comment: Hello, is this done in WinEdt?

Comment: No, that's an operating system thing. I don't use Windows, but try a [search for "windows set environment variable"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+set+environment+variable). Alternatively, replace `%makeglossaries_path%` with the full path to the `makeglossaries` perl script. However, I gather that MikTeX has an executable version `makeglossaries.exe` which should be installed with the `glossaries` package, so if you installed `glossaries` with the package manager, you should simply be able to use `makeglossaries.exe` instead.