# List of symbols and abbreviations separately

Tags: symbols, glossaries, nomenclature, nomencl

I needed to get list of symbols and abbreviations for my thesis, by following the MWE which I have got from [How to create both list of abbreviations and list of nomenclature using nomencl package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl)
I was able to get two separate lists, but I want them separately on different pages, like list of symbols and abbreviations.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%% This removes the main title:
\renewcommand{\nomname}{}
%% this modifies item separation:
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}
%% this part defines the groups:
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\Large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Nomenclature}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{List of Abbreviations}{}}%
]\vspace{10pt}} % this is to add vertical space between the groups.
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{IMO}}{in my opinion}
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{OP}}{original poster}
\nomenclature[N]{$c$}{speed of light in vacuum}
\nomenclature[N]{$h$}{Plank constant}

\printnomenclature[2cm]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This version avoids the initial `\clearpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\newif\iffirstglossary\firstglossarytrue
%% This removes the main title:
\renewcommand{\nomname}{}
%% this modifies item separation:
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{8pt}
%% this part defines the groups:
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
\iffirstglossary
\firstglossaryfalse
\else
\clearpage
\fi
  \item[\Large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Nomenclature}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{List of Abbreviations}{}}%
]\vspace{10pt}} % this is to add vertical space between the groups.
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
Here we go!

\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{IMO}}{in my opinion}
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{OP}}{original poster}
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{CDM}}{carefully driving marmot}
\nomenclature[N]{$c$}{speed of light in vacuum}
\nomenclature[N]{$h$}{Planck constant}
\nomenclature[N]{$w$}{average weight of a marmot}

\printnomenclature[2cm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This works fine but, now the first page is having the actual chapter style spacing at the beginning, but the second group is starting at the beginning of the page without any spacing. Can this be solved?

Comment: Yes. Just replace the `\clearpage` between `\else` and `\fi` by `\clearpage~\medskip\medskip`. (I think that this spacing will depend on the the document class in general, so I adjusted it by hand. Whether there is a way to always get the right amount, I don't know.)