# How to add acronym/glossaries table in LaTeX with documentclass `scrreprt` or `report`?

Tags: glossaries, scrreprt

I followed this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666) and try to run a simple code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% abbreviations:
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}

% nomenclature:
\newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
 name = $a$ ,
 description = The number of angels per unit area,
}

\newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
 name = $N$ ,
 description = The number of angels per needle point
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\gls{ny}, \gls{la} are abbreviations whereas

\gls{angelsperarea}, \gls{numofangels} are part of the nomenclature

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

\printglossary[title=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

above code segment correctly display acronyms if I use document class `article` as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
```

but it doesn't show any output if document class is `scrreprt` as below:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
```

Tex Version:

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

Comment: How do you build your documents? You need to incorporate `makeglossaries` into the process. See [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries).