# How to make only a list of abbreviations?

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

I am using [How to create both list of abbreviations and list of nomenclature using nomencl package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl) to create a list of abbreviations. The code is below:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\Large\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{N}{Nomenclature}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{List of Abbreviations}{}}%
]\vspace{10pt}}



\begin{document}

\makenomenclature
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{LC/MS-MS}}{liquid chromatography-tandem mass spectrometry }
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{DDA}}{data dependent acquisition}
\nomenclature[A]{\textbf{PRM}}{parallel reaction monitoring}
\printnomenclature[2cm]

\end{document}
```

How can I delete **Nomenclature** and leave only **List of Abbreviations** in the final document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redefine `\nomname`. You don't need the optional arguments; by redefining `\nomlabel` you can automatically get boldface.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\textbf{#1}\hfil}

\begin{document}

Some text

\nomenclature{LC/MS-MS}{liquid chromatography-tandem mass spectrometry }
\nomenclature{DDA}{data dependent acquisition}
\nomenclature{PRM}{parallel reaction monitoring}

\printnomenclature[2.5cm]

\end{document}
```

[image]